# How can I find out what command a shortcut was assigned to?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

Yesterday I wasn't thinking and assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to a command.  I can't recall what program I was in or what command I assigned.  Now, of course, I can't use that shortcut to paste.

How do I find out what I assigned this shortcut to, and re-assign to *paste*?

Comment: Press `Ctrl-V`. What happens? It should give you a hint about what you assigned it to.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same program you used to assign <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> to return it to `paste`.
If you just press <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> you will see what happens now and will know what action it executes.
Then if you cannot re-assign back to `paste`, just reset the settings or load default profile in that program you used for re-assigning.